# SQL update with two tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 tables, 1 is current and 1 is log.
If current have any changed, will update the state from 0 to 1 and copy whole table to log table.
May I know the update statements?

```
<CURRENT>
Date            Name          Money  Currency       Money_Change     Currency_Change
10/1/2014       ABC           14       HKD            0  -> 1              0
10/1/2014       BCD           11       USD            0                    0  -> 1
10/1/2014       DCE           18       RMB            0  -> 1              0  -> 1


<LOG>
Date            Name          Money   Currency 
7/1/2014        ABC           2         HKD     
7/1/2014        BCD           11        EUR
7/1/2014        DCE           16        CAD
2/1/2014        ABC           10        HKD
2/1/2014        BCD           12        RMB
2/1/2014        DCE           1         CAD
1/1/2014        ABC           10        HKD
1/1/2014        BCD           12        RMB
1/1/2014        DCE           16        USD
```

Comment: You must make an effort in writing the statement(s) yourself. Once you've made an attempt, you can seek assistance with them.

Comment: I'd go with a trigger based solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very weird way to log changes. your log table will grow immensely. Do you want to insert changes before or after change? If after change do it like this:

```
UPDATE CURRENT SET MONEY=1 
INSERT INTO LOGS
SELECT * from CURRENT
```